# Email or socket communication between servers

Tags: node.js, sockets, email, zeromq, server-communication

I know this is an odd questions but it is one that has come up in a group I am working with and has been one of great debate. I will try and explain what we are trying to do to the best of my knowledge.

Basically we have multiple servers that are responsible for processing data. We need some kind of communication between them to pass data and possibly commands and one side of the group is interested in using some type of socket communication such as node.js or ZeroMQ and the other group wants to use email between the servers to communicate with one another.

So this question goes out to any communication experts or anyone that might have an opinion on this matter. Which would be the most suitable for scalability, ease of deployment or just an overall better system design? Why do you think this? Any other suggestions?

Thank you and any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered in a single discussion and there is no right answer to it. I wouldn't recommend to use email-based communication between servers and to implement a protocol like the [Advanced Message Queuing Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) (to which ZeroMQ in my eyes belongs to) but that's just my two cents.

Comment: I know it is somewhat broad, the nature of the project restricts how much detail I can get into. Thank you though for your feedback.

Comment: If these are all the details you can (legally?) add to your question, Stackoverflow may be the wrong place to ask. There are too many answers based on too many unknowns that are going to yield an answer that *other people* will also benefit from (a requirement for SO answers - it's just not just for you, but for everyone else who has a question like yours)

Answer (score 1):

Though I agree with the comments about the suitability of this question for SO, I can't imagine any scenario in which I would prefer email as a communication medium to a direct socket connection, or an HTTP-based API. It might sound cool to get it working, but it's almost certainly a path to headaches.